# Error 2 in Pycharm working with Jupyter Notebooks. No such file or directory exist

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ubuntu-19.04

I have anaconda, using pycharm pro, when I try to run a "hello, world" to to test my notebook I get the error:

> Cannot run program "/home/tyrin/anaconda3/envs/JupyterTest/bin/jupyter" (in directory "/home/tyrin/PycharmProjects/JupyterTest"): error=2, No such file or directory

Does anyone had this problem and solved it?

```
Code:print("Hello, world")
```

Comment: I suppose that you´re editing your jupyter notebook from that app in the browser, not in pycharm..are you trying to run an .ipynb file in pycharm?

Comment: Yes i am using .ipnyb

Comment: From Jupyter notebook browser app you can download it as a .py file, all the markdown comments are converted in comments in a .py file, so you can run that .py

Comment: thanks I'll do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your notebook as a py, then you can run it in at the terminal or pycharm

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked so I'll just stick to the browser version